# How to specify authorizer custom error codes when using serverless

Tags: serverless

I have an authorizer for my api. It returns a 401 status code on failed authorization. I want to return custom status code (410) as I am using 401 else where in the application. I want a different behavior on client side when it gets a status code of 410

```
functions:

authorizerFunc:
  handler: authorize.handler

# Roles API
getRoles:
  handler: allrolesget.handler
  events:
    - http:
        path: /
        method: get
        cors: true
        integration: lambda
        authorizer:
          name: authorizerFunc
          resultTtlInSeconds: 0
          identitySource: method.request.header.Authorization
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't change status code of custom authorizer. What you can do - remove custom authorizer and make custom authorization in lambda - there you have full control of what status code should be returned.